# Multiple reproduction of songs with audio tag and js

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a js function like this:

```
function riproduci(link) {
var ar = link.split("*");
var s = ar[0];
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "incremento.php?link="+s, true);
xhttp.send();
audio.load(s);
audio.play();
}
```

In the link parameter there is a sequence of links separated with the * character, so i split the string into the different links. So, in order to try i have sent to the audio script the link 0 in the array, now i want to perform this: when a song, is finished (so, something with the onEnded() event) to go and take the next link and to load this to the player automatically. I have no idea on how can I access the link just ended in order the choose the next.

Please don't consider the ajax code that is part of the function, that is not involved with the question that I'm asking to you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write this function based on the instruction given:

```
function riproduci(link) {
let i = 0;
var ar = link.split("*");
var n = ar.length;
var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
audio.addEventListener("ended", rp);
audio.load(ar[0]);
audio.play();
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("titolo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "incremento.php?link="+ar[0], true);
xhttp.send();
function rp(e){
    i++;
    i = (i >= n) ? 0 : i;
    var l = ar[i];
    this.load(ar[i]);
    this.play();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("titolo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "incremento.php?link="+l, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

But I don't know why, it goes into an infinite loop, it starts playing all the songs in the sequence of link passed but going from one to the other in less than one second. What's wrong?

UPDATE: The player is loaded with an empty song of less than one second, if i perform the riproduci() function the src of the audio tag doesn't change and the empty "song" goes into an infinite loop.

UPDATE 2: This is my audio player.

```
<div id="pers_player_footer">
        <script src="../audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            audiojs.events.ready(function() {
            var as = audiojs.createAll();
            window.audio = as[0];
            });
        </script>
        <audio id="audio" src="../songs/empty.mp3" autoplay='true'/>
</div>
```

UPDATE 3: The updated function

```
function riproduci(link) {
var as = audiojs.createAll();
let i = 0;
var ar = link.split("*");
var n = ar.length;
var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
audio.addEventListener("ended", rp);
audio.src = ar[0];
audio.load();
audio.play();
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("titolo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "incremento.php?link="+ar[0], true);
xhttp.send();
function rp(e){
    i++;
    i = (i >= n) ? 0 : i;
    var l = ar[i];
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
    audio.src = ar[i];
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("titolo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "incremento.php?link="+l, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

This is the link of where I found the audio library: https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/